# SQLite 3 OperationalError cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to populate a database table using `sqlalchemy`.

I'm using [`dataset`](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to write to the database.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import exc
import dataset
import sqlite3

Base = declarative_base()

class Eticks(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Eticks'
    id = Column(String(25),primary_key=True)
    affected_vers = Column(String(250),primary_key=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///work_items.db', pool_recycle=3600)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def format_vers(versobj):
    if isinstance(versobj,list):
        return " - ".join(versobj)
    else:
        return versobj

for i in list_of_objects:
    with dataset.connect('sqlite:///work_items.db',
                         engine_kwargs={'pool_recycle': 3600}) as table:
        table['Eticks'].upsert(dict(id=i.id,
        affected_vers=format_vers(getattr(i,'Affected versions','Unspecified'))),['id'])
```

I've used this exact same syntax before for another table, however I'm now getting an error when I try it here:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: 
(sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

The list that I'm looping through is quite large - 24,000 items - could that be related?

I've also noticed that the error gets thrown more quickly if I use `table['Eticks'].upsert` rather than  `.insert`

As I said, this syntax worked perfectly for another table, so I can't see what's caused this issue.

Can anyone help?